# Javascript - Check if email configured

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mailto

We can send a mail using `mailto:` in HTML and JavaScript. Is there any possible method to check if the email is configured (i.e. whether any default email service to send email - such as Outlook - is available)?

I need to handle this

```
if(emailConfigured == true)

{
    // send mail

} else {

    // give alert
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by e-mail configured?

Comment: Btw, `if(emailConfigured)` is sufficient

Comment: To check whether any default email service to send email, like Outlook is available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't do this. It is completely impossible. The JavaScript environment has no access to the host computer to tell if something is configured to handle `mailto:` links. That is so far outside the bounds of your webapp's responsibility that you should not and can not worry about it. It's not your page's job to figure out if the user knows how to send emails.

Comment: True but using a timeout to check is a decent workaround:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176849/what-does-mailto-do-when-there-is-no-email-client

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be possible to use javascript to open new email window and check afterwards if the window changed?

```
   window.location.assign("mailto:abc@axample-test.com?Subject=ABC);
```

If it the window did not change, you can conclude that the email is not properly configured.

Comment: This solution works:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176849/what-does-mailto-do-when-there-is-no-email-client

Answer (score -1):

you can add following html if email configured by php or ... and do :

```
<!-- html -->
<input type="hidden" value="mymail@gmail.com" id="mailto" />


// Javascript
if($("#mailto")[0])

{
    // send mail
 window.location = "mailto:"+#("mailto").val();

} else {

    // give alert
}
```

Comment: This no different than simply adding a `mailto:` link, and has the very unpleasant side-effect of requiring JavaScript where it's not needed.

Comment: @meagar it can be used for custiom plugin, more than one link with small edit.. however this Q is funky

Comment: I'm sorry, but there is literally no situation in which the above code is useful. It can always, *always* be replaced with a single `<a href="mailto:whatever">` link that does the same job without a blob of JavaScript.